# Selenium element search after go in new URL using Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have a page `example.com/user` has two fields name and email.
After send form it's go in `example.com/preview`
In preview page I need to submit the from.

I written below code

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://example.com/user.php")

old_url = driver.current_url;

print(old_url);
print("===============")

email  = driver.find_element_by_name("mail")
name   = driver.find_element_by_name("name")

email.send_keys("example@mail.com")
name.send_keys("Jone")


form = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[1]")
form.submit()
print("=====From submited====")

driver.implicitly_wait(40)

new_url = driver.current_url
print(new_url)  **#still printing old URL**


try:
    element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No element found")


driver.save_screenshot('sc.png')
```

I am trying to grab preview page form to submit. But I am unable to grab preview page form. So here I am trying to give a condition like

```
if(old_url !=current_url) 
then 
 element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']")  #form find in preview page
```

But I am unable to do ! How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [ExplicitWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) as below to continue code execution after navigated to new URL:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

...
form.submit()    
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.current_url != old_url)
new_url = driver.current_url
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are only getting this page "http://example.com/user.php".

```
def get_url(base_url):
    return driver.get(base_url)

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
base_url = 'http://example.com/user.php'

get_url(base_url)

print(old_url);
print("===============")

email  = driver.find_element_by_name("mail")
name   = driver.find_element_by_name("name")

email.send_keys("example@mail.com")
name.send_keys("Jone")

get_url(driver.current_url) #getting form url

form = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[1]")
form.submit()
print("=====From submited====")

driver.implicitly_wait(40)
```